# Backlight inverter and newer laptops?

Tags: laptop, lcd, backlight

My notebook, an Asus model X44H, got its screen broken. I replaced it with another screen and, although not the same model, it worked and all was fine.
I forgot the charger and it lost its energy, so I got a replacement charger.

Now I can see the image only when using a flashlight on the screen. It seems like a backlight problem, but I cannot seem to find a backlight inverter for this model. Does the screen itself have this inverter?

Comment: I have an ASPIRE 1410 with the same problem, lack of a backlight. On my model, the entire screen needs to be replaced, as the light is built into the screen. No separate inverter exists. I am not sure if the screen is the same as yours. You mention that you changed the charger - are you saying that the backlight only stopped working after you changed te charger. Do you suspect the charger of having caused the backlight to fail?

Comment: As far as I can tell without knowing the model number of your LCD screen is that the Asus X44H screens have LED backlight's so no inverter.

Comment: Is the inverter on the pcb embedded in the LCD screen ?  I guess i need to open the computer when i have the correct tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the notebook, and I can see there is no inverter anywhere.

Apparently the inverter was embedded in the screen's electronics and seem to burn again, Will need to buy another LCD model for the screen.